# Is possible to search in vim history?

Tags: vim

On bash I press CTRL+R and typing vim bash return list of commands typed in past with vim string.Is possible to make something like this in vim history for commands starting with the : ?

Comment: Dont forget about [vi.se] !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may move up and down through the commands saved in Vim's command history by using the <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> keys after having typed <kbd>:</kbd>.

If you enter the start of a command and press <kbd>Up</kbd>, Vim will give you the most recent saved command with the same prefix string. In this respect it works in the reverse order from what Bash uses in that you *first* type in a bit of a command and *then* press <kbd>Up</kbd> (rather than, as in Bash, first press <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> and then type something).

This also works for search strings.

Answer (score 16):

When you type `q:` **Vim** opens `[Command Line]` window. In this window you can normally search by pressing `?` (backward) or `/` or browse by arrows... You can execute selected line by pressing enter.

See chapter 20.5 of help in **Vim** for details. Type `:help usr_20.txt`, then go to with cursor to `|20.5|` and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>:

> Open the command line window with this command: >

```
    q:
```

> Vim now opens a (small) window at the bottom.  It contains the command line
>   history, and an empty line at the end:

```
    +-------------------------------------+
    |other window                         |
    |~                                    |
    |file.txt=============================|
    |:e c                                 |
```